# vars(count) declared outside of the function won't work, which's inside the if else inside of a function

Tags: javascript

as in title, I am making a number-guessing game. And the document.getelementbyid inside the if-else of a function returns undefined.

```
var count = 5;
function checkans() {
        console.log(count);
        var UIC = document.getElementById("usrinput");
        
        

        console.log(UIC.value); 
        console.log(c1 + count + c2);
         //main
         if (count > 0)
         {
         if (UIC.value > ranNum) {
            document.getElementById("tips").innerHTML = "The number is too large!";
            var count = count - 1;
            document.getElementById("chance").innerHTML = (c1 + count + c2);
            document.getElementById("totalChances").innerHTML = (count);
            

         } else if (UIC.value < ranNum) {
            document.getElementById("tips").innerHTML = "The number is too small!";
            var count = count - 1;
            document.getElementById("chance").innerHTML = (c1 + count + c2);
            document.getElementById("totalChances").innerHTML = (count);



         } else {
            document.getElementById("tips").innerHTML = "Congrats! The number is correct. "
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` will never return `undefined`. What exactly is `undefined`? Where? Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre].

Comment: Remove the `var` from both lines `var count = count - 1;`